# fresco can't be built by Gradle after imported into Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, gradle, fresco

We know the Facebook Technology Team open-sourced `fresco` about 5 days ago. And I git it from Github. And then I imported the whole project, afterwards I tried to build the `sample`, but AS can't make it. Errors are here:
[image]
And:
[image]

And I have changed `gradle.properties` into this:

```
target=22
VERSION_NAME=0.1.0
GROUP=com.facebook.fresco

# Deps for gradle
ANDROID_GRADLE_PLUGIN_VERSION=1.1.0
GRADLE_DOWNLOAD_TASK_VERSION=1.2
GRADLE_GIT_CLONE_TASK_VERSION=0.0.2
ROBOLECTRIC_GRADLE_PLUGIN_VERSION=0.14.1

# Deps for libraries
ANNOTATION_API_VERSION=[1.2,)
BOLTS_ANDROID_VERSION=1.1.4
FEST_ASSERT_CORE_VERSION=2.0M10
GUAVA_VERSION=18.0
JSR_305_VERSION=[3.0,)
JUNIT_VERSION=4.12
OKHTTP_VERSION=2.2.0
MOCKITO_CORE_VERSION=[1.0,)
NINEOLDANDROID_VERSION=2.4.0
POWERMOCK_MOCKITO_RELEASE_FULL_VERSION=1.5.5
POWERMOCK_MODULE_JUNIT4_RULE_VERSION=1.6.1
ROBOLECTRIC_VERSION=2.4
SUPPORT_V4_VERSION=22.0.0
VOLLEY_VERSION=1.0.6

#Deps for sample app
APPCOMPAT_V7_VERSION=22.0.0
GLIDE_VERSION=3.5.2
UIL_VERSION=1.9.4
PICASSO_VERSION=2.5.2
```

What's more, My Android Studio is 1.1.0, Gradle 2.2.1, ADT 22.
I felt it's the matter of plugins with different versions. But I don't have a solution. So, could anybody help me or have any idea?

Comment: Perhaps you should post a question on the github page for that project?

Comment: Hi, Do post the solution here if you get one, am also stuck on the same issue..

Comment: @Jalpesh the Github issue is [here](https://github.com/facebook/fresco/issues/67), the Facebook fresco Team had not a solution by far.

Answer (score 0):

This is now fixed. If you download the latest source it should work.